# Using shouldComponentUpdate to prevent jitter on rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue with my React application when loading the next page of items. Some sections of the page load before others and some sections load with data from the previous page before quickly switching to data from the new one. The functionality works fine, but it looks a bit janky.

I have solved this issue by adding state to determine whether the component is loading the next page, and only updating it when it isn't loading.

```
async nextPage(){
  this.setState({isLoading: true})
  await apiCall()
  this.setState({isLoading: false})
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
    return !this.state.isLoading
}
```

This seems like bad practice and something that could cause unrelated consequences. Is there a cleaner solution for this issue?

Comment: Seems ok/valid to me. The alternative is applying conditional rendering of some "loading" UI in the render return.

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate is meant to tell React that the component's output isn't affected by a change in props/state. It's advised not to use shouldComponentUpdate to prevent a render when there is actually a change in the component's output. The preferred practice would be conditional rendering dependent on the loading state (e.g. only rendering elements once loading is completed, or rendering loading indicator components in place of elements while waiting on updated data).